# MediaStore returns null when querying for DISPLAY_NAME

Tags: android, mediastore

In some rare situations, `MediaStore` returns `null` when trying to query for `MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DISPLAY_NAME` using the following code snippet

```
String displayName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));
```

I guess it might be related to a file name, since it is only reported on a few devies. However I assume that file display names can't be null, so it is a bit weird that `MediaStore` returns `null`. Has anybody experienced a similar problem?

Comment: It is nullable for Android 9 and lower. But on Android 10+, it is made non-null.

Comment: @AnggrayudiH How can it become null? I was looking at `MediaProvider` and it seems that the `DATA` column is used for finding `DISPLAY_NAME` indirectly when the direct query returns null. How can the `DATA` field become null for a file present on the storage?

Comment: The DATA field has been deprecated in Android 10, and may or not contain any data at all. The most logical is that if DISPLAY_NAME is empty then the TITLE field should be the most logical alternative field, although this field does not contain the media extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have the same problem on one device.

If the DISPLAY_NAME is null the TITLE can be used.

```
String displayName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));
if (displayName == null) {
    displayName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.TITLE));
}
```